# Sufficient condition for $\langle Ax, Ay\rangle\leq \lambda^2_{max}\langle x, y\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-decomposition, spectral-norm

**Question.** Is there a ''non-trivial'' sufficient condition on $x, y\in \mathbb R^n$ such that
$$\langle Ax, Ay\rangle\leq \lambda^2_{\max}\langle x, y\rangle$$
where $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $\lambda_{\max}>0$ is the largest [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$.

**''Trivial'' case.**
If $x=y$, it is well-known that
$$||Ax||^2\leq \lambda_{\max}^2||x||^2$$
and $\lambda_{\max}$ is called the [spectral norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html) of $A$.

Comment: Decompose $y$ into the part $y_{\parallel}$ parallel to $x$ and $y_{\perp}$ perpendicular to $x$.

When $y_{\parallel} = kx$ with $k \geq 0$, $LHS = \langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \langle A^TA x, y_{\parallel} + y_{\perp}\rangle \leq \lambda_{max}^2 \langle x, y_{\parallel}\rangle + \langle A^TAx, y_{\perp}\rangle.$

$RHS = \lambda_{max}^2 \langle x, y_{\parallel}\rangle + \lambda_{max}^2 \langle x, y_{\perp}\rangle = \lambda_{max}^2 \langle x, y_{\parallel}\rangle.$

So I think it suffices to have $\langle A^TAx, y_{\perp}\rangle \leq 0$.

Comment: @VezenBU, it is indeed an interesting idea, thanks!